# Using a VBA- looking to construct a code that, depending on entered or chosen information in excel, will auto-populate a sentence in word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, excel-2007

Using a VBA- looking to construct a code that, depending on entered or chosen information in excel, will auto-populate a sentence in word.

For Example...

*In Excel:*

```
Question                            Answer 
What is his Name?                   John 
How many apples did he buy?         8 
How much did the apples cost?       50
```

*In Word:*

```
John bought 8 apples totalling $ 50 dollars.
```

**Based on the information typed in the answer column (excel spreadsheet) I would want a word document to automatically generate a sentence.**

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Metfan755

Comment: Yes, it's quite possible.  Have you tried anything?  If Yes, what code did you try, and what happened? If No, try something then edit your question to include your code and any problems you ran into.

Comment: Hey Tim, I have tried a number of codes that I have found online but they just transfer the data as opposed to actually adding writing in between. I'm just getting into programming so I don't have much knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of (pseudo-code):

```
dim writing as string
writing=Sheets("x").Cells(y, z)   
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")     
objWord.Visible = True     
Selection.InsertAfter (writing)
```

perhaps?

Adding whatever other parts of the sentence you need to writing also

Comment: if the information I was looking to pull from was in cells b2:b4 where would i put that?

Comment: @the other one `Cells(y, z)` would refer to the cell in row `y`, column `z` (where `y` and `z` are integer/long variables with non-zero value).  One issue is that here, people generally don't write code from scratch for you; so if you have tried some things (even if they didn't do exactly what you want) show us what you have tried and explain how that is not working. There are more than enough ppl here who can help you if you show what you've tried, first.